# Adding Token to Header Soap in Java

Tags: java, soap, http-headers, token

I want to add a security token to a header SOAP through Java. The header should look like this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:actor="http://www.example.com/soap/actor/wssecurity" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" S12:role="wsssecurity" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:S12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="SSOToken" ValueType="esquema" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">TOKEN_HERE</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I have this example when I need to add an user and password to the HTTP header:

```
Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)client).getRequestContext();
req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("AplicationID", Collections.singletonList("id"));
req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

How can I add a token to the header using the same approach as the code block above?

Thanks